# What is the purpose of a resistor in series with a potentiometer?

Tags: resistors, potentiometer, zener, series

I assume the 100 Ohm resistor is in series with the potentiometer so that the circuit is not shorted if the potentiometer has a value of 0 ohms, however, I know that will not affect the circuit because of the Zener diode. Can someone explain thoroughly please?

[image]

Comment: maybe it just needs some offset from zero.

Comment: If the **function** of the circuit is *Voltage Regulator* as labelled in the schematic, shorting \$v_0\$ (by removing 100 ohm and turning the potmeter to 0 ohm **definitely** will affect the circuit.

Comment: Depending on construction Rmin is usually 3% of Rmax but if it were 0, the difference in voltage is    9mA * 100 ohm = 0.9V  But it could be more due to the 3%

Comment: It gives the load circuit a minimum resistance. Otherwise the load will be short-circuited if you turn the pot' down to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the resistor is only needed if a minimum resistance is desired to eg. set a minimum output voltage or simulate a maximum load. The 1k resistor in the shunt regulator should prevent too much current from flowing even if the pot is set to zero Ohms.

However in many circuits the pot might short out other parts of the circuit, causing excessively high current or overloading a signal output. It is also a good idea to add a resistor in experimental circuits where the pot might might be wired incorrectly. For example if you connect it across the power supply rails as voltage divider but have the center and outside terminals crossed over, the pot track may burn up when turned to minimum resistance at that end.